# Set custom width and height for DialogFragment

Tags: android, layout, android-dialogfragment

I had a DialogFragment with TableLayout inside. When I executed my code the DialogFragment height occupied my whole screen. I am using RelativeLayout.  Can anyone help me to set custom width and height of a DialogFragment in Android? This is what I have done, but won't work for me:

```
Window view_dialog = getDialog().getWindow();
        view_dialog.setTitle("MODE :  CONNECTION");
        view_dialog.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = view_dialog.getAttributes();
        parameters.y = dptopx(60);
        view_dialog.setAttributes(parameters);


private int dptopx(int i) {
        DisplayMetrics measurements = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, i, measurements);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get screen `height` and `width` with `displaymatrix` and then put your desired size depending on the height and width.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.height = height - (height/5); 
lp.width = width - 80;

dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```